# Carriage return in post request

Tags: python, post, python-requests, carriage-return

I have a textarea on a website which send data with post.. I need to replicate the post request in my python application.

In textarea I have tested with these data :

```
test1:hello
test2:thanks
```

The request form data source in Chrome inspector is : `test1%3Bhello%0D%0Atest2%3Bthanks`

What can I put in payload in my python app post request as carriage return ? `\r\n` or `%0D%0A` ? Thanks !

I have tried to put `\r\n` in the textarea but it gives me `%5Cr%5Cn` and `%0D%0A` gives me `%250D%250A`.

Comment: Not sure what your goal is, if you want to send `test1%3Bhello%0D%0Atest2%3Bthanks` just send it

Comment: Okay thanks, I was afraid the %0D%0A would be parsed again

Comment: That was wrong, the correct thing to do was send \r\n